# Is it even possible to solve this differential equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, differential-equations

Last year I was an AP Physics 1 student, and I gave myself an insane problem out of curiosity. I had no clue why I couldn't solve it, and I now see why it's a much more complicated problem than I thought. The scenario is simple:

A frictionless inclined plane of length $l$ holds a block of mass $m$. The angle is not specified, but a starting height is, and the incline "height" increases at a constant rate (think of it like the incline points toward a point that is going up at a constant rate).

[image: the illustration]

My goal is to find the final velocity of the block's motion once it travels the distance $l$, the length of the incline, assuming it starts perfectly on its edge to travel through it all.

What I came up with was a second-order non-linear differential equation.
The motion of this block can be specified by:
$$
\ddot x = g\sin \theta
$$
And knowing the base of this "triangle" is $\sqrt {l^2 - h_0^2}$, we know $\sin \theta$:
$$
\ddot x = \frac {hg} {\sqrt {h^2  + l^2 - h_0^2}}
$$
Where h is the "height" of where the incline is pointing at any time. The reason this is so complex to me is that x and h are both functions of time, yet this differential equation ties them together in a way I cannot wrap my head around.

To make sure this equation was true, I graphed $\ddot x$ with respect to the height on Desmos, with $h_0$ assumed to be 0. As expected, it should approach $g$ as the angle approaches a right angle due to the height going to infinity, so I know my differential equation is sound.

[image: the graph]

What I tried to do to make progress was turn the second-order differential into a first-order in terms of velocity.
$$
{\frac {d^2x} {{dx}^2} = \frac {dv} {dt} = ({\frac {dh} {dt}})({\frac {dv} {dh}})}
$$
And $\frac {dh} {dt}$ is a given constant from the start, so this allows me to separate the equation and integrate one side for velocity, and the other side for height. From here, I am completely lost. I attempted to go on from here several times now but have gotten stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to complicate things further, I think your equation of motion is incorrect.  If there was no gravity, and you rotated the ramp as you describe, you'd expect the block to move outwards from the rotation point;  it can't stay put because if it did it would be moving in a circle and when $g = 0$ there's no force that can provide the requisite centripetal force.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I should add that I assume $g$ is a positive number greater than 0. Apologies. I always assume the box will tend to go downward

Comment: The better way to get the differential equation would be to write out [Newton's Laws in polar coordinates](http://mechanicsmap.psu.edu/websites/9_newtons_particle/9-4_polar_equations_of_motion/polar_equations_of_motion.html).  But this will, I'm afraid, just make the equation harder to solve exactly.  Very few differential equations have exactly solutions, I'm afraid, and you'll probably have to resort to numerical solutions for a particular set of initial conditions.

Comment: @Matteo I believe that is not correct. The base of the triangle shall stay constant, imagine it like the incline is rotating to point toward a point whose height is increasing. In this way, the "hypotenuse" is also changing to represent $sin\theta$ while the length of the incline itself is not, and this is taken into account by my equation of motion

Comment: My point still stands.  Even if the block is sliding down the plane, you can't just drop the term in the equations of motion that would drive the box "upwards" due to the rotation of the plane, any more than you could drop the frictional force in such a case.  It still affects the motion of the block, even if the net effect is a "downward" force.

Comment: @HydroPage yeah I deleted the comment as I realized that I misunderstood the problem :) thanks

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I understand what you're saying. I didn't consider that at all. Are there any assumptions I can make that would let me ignore that effect, or is it unavoidable? I don't even know how I would analyze that

Comment: It's unavoidable.  The way to account for it would be to use polar coordinates, with the point of rotation being at the origin (i.e., $r$ is the distance along the ramp.)  See the link I posted above.  There's also a technique that you'll probably encounter in future physics courses called [Lagrangian mechanics;](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/david-morin/files/cmchap6.pdf) which makes the analysis of problems like this one rather easier.

Comment: I was indeed wondering if the Euler-Lagrange equation would have something to say about this

Comment: Could you find the speed of rotation required so that the block doesn't move? i.e. downward force equals upward force .....

Comment: What makes this difficult I think is that having $\dot{h}$ be a constant implies the block is on a plane going through *accelerated* rotation, that is, since we have $h=l\sin{\theta}$, $\ddot{\theta}$ does not vanish. You may want to try and solve a slightly easier version of this problem where instead you have $\dot{\theta}$ constant ;)

Comment: (...sorry $h=r\sin{\theta}$ because you're taking $l$ to be the constant length of the ramp and not the radial position... but the point remains the same)